# Orthonormal basis and coordinate systems

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

Determine the co-ordinates of $x$ =(9, 10, 11), $v_1$ -$4v_2$ and $v_3$ with respect to $v_1, v_2, v_3$.

$v_1$ = ($\frac{1}{3}$,-$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{2}{3}$)

$v_2$ = ($\frac{2}{3}$,-$\frac{1}{3}$,-$\frac{2}{3}$)

$v_3$ = ($\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{2}{3}$,$\frac{1}{3}$)

Comment: I have calculated $v_1 - 4v_2$ = $\frac{67}{3}$
and 
$v_3$ =$\frac{49}{3}$
But think I am totally getting the wrong end of the stick and that there should be 3 co-ordinates and that I am reading it incorrectly.

Comment: Go back to definitions: what does it mean for a tuple of scalars to be the coordinates of a vector in some basis?

Comment: It was written without a comma and I read it as 2 co-ordinates but it is 3 correct?

Answer (score 1):

Basis $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is orthonormal, so you can find coordinates of a vector in this basis by taking the dot product of the vector and basis vectors, so since $\langle v_1,x\rangle=11/3,\langle v_2,x\rangle=-14/3,\langle v_3,x\rangle=49/3$ coordinates of $x$ in this basis are $(11/3,-14/3,49/3)$, you can find coordinates of $v_1-4v_2$ similarly.

Comment: For $v_1-4v_2$ there’s no reason to go to even that small amount of work: its coordinates in the given basis ought to be self-evident.